# Opencart 3.0.2.0 sending email with mail() funtion

Tags: php, email, opencart-3

I want to send an email to everyone who subscribes to my newsletter. In order to do this i wrote the following code inside a method i created in catalog->controller->common->footer.php.

```
         $to = "mymail@yahoo.com";
         $subject = "-5% Έκπτωση στο ioannoustores.com";
         
         $message = "Χρησιμοποιήστε το εκπτωτικό κουπόνι στις αγορές σας και κερδίστε 5% έκπτωση. Ο κωδικός σας είναι: " . $res . " και ισχύει για 7 ημέρες.";
         
         
         $header = "From:info@ioannoustores.com \r\n";
         
         
         
         mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

I used the exact same code in opencart 2.1 and it worked but in 3.0.2.0 it doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$to = "mymail@yahoo.com";
         $subject = "-5% Έκπτωση στο ioannoustores.com";
         
         $message = "Χρησιμοποιήστε το εκπτωτικό κουπόνι στις αγορές σας και κερδίστε 5% έκπτωση. Ο κωδικός σας είναι: " . $res . " και ισχύει για 7 ημέρες.";
         
         
         $header = "From:info@ioannoustores.com \r\n";
```

try this:

```
$mail = new Mail($this->config->get('config_mail_engine'));
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

$mail->setTo($to);
$mail->setFrom('your@email.xxx');
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode('Shop Name', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($message);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: it didnt work unfortunately. and i cant find anything in the erro.log

Comment: Did you add suggested code after your code where:` $to; subject; $message; and $header;` ? It should work. Have you changed ` 'your@email.xxx'` to your email?

Comment: You are correct it works juuust fine. I just messed up a little bit. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: you can mark my answer as useful.

Comment: i did but it wont let me. i dont have enough reputation